# IIS reverses web site settings when stopping

Tags: iis, application-settings

I have an issue with configuring IIS. I programmatically create a web site and an application (virtual dir) under the web site. Among other settings, I add a wildcard application map in the applications settings. When IIS is restarted, it removes the wilcard application map (and some other settings, but I just mention the wilcard map for simplicity). I can re-add the map, using IIS manager, but when I restart IIS, the map is removed. BUT - if I add the wildcard map and then, without restarting IIS, use a browser first to hit a page in that application, then any subsequent IIS restarts do not cause the map to disappear. Any idea what's going on?

here's my code:

```
// root virtual dir object
string strRootVirtDirPath = "IIS://localhost/w3svc/" + strWebSiteID + "/root";
DirectoryEntry deRootVirtDir = new DirectoryEntry(strRootVirtDirPath);

// add new virtual dir
DirectoryEntry deNewVirtDir = deRootVirtDir.Children.Add(strAppName, "IIsWebVirtualDir");

deNewVirtDir.Properties["Path"].Value = strPhysicalDir;
deNewVirtDir.Properties["AppFriendlyName"].Value = strAppName;
deNewVirtDir.Properties["AppRoot"].Value = "/LM/W3SVC/" + strWebSiteID + "/Root/" + strAppName;
deNewVirtDir.Properties["AppPoolId"].Value = strAppPoolName;

// create the application
deNewVirtDir.Invoke("AppCreate", 1);

// commit changes
deNewVirtDir.CommitChanges();
deRootVirtDir.CommitChanges();
deNewVirtDir.Close();
deRootVirtDir.Close();
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention it's IIS 6

Comment: Did you correctly call .Invoke("AppCreate") when creating your virtual directory, and then .CommitChanges() after updating your settings?

Comment: Not sure how to verify if the function calls are correct. The code executes successfully, I don't get any exceptions. Here's my code:

Comment: // create root virtual dir object
                string strRootVirtDirPath = "IIS://localhost/w3svc/" + strWebSiteIDLocal + "/root";
                DirectoryEntry deRootVirtDir = new DirectoryEntry(strRootVirtDirPath);

                // add new virtual dir
                DirectoryEntry deNewVirtDir = deRootVirtDir.Children.Add(strApplicationNameLocal, "IIsWebVirtualDir");

                // set physical dir
                deNewVirtDir.Properties["Path"].Value = strRootDir;

Comment: // set properties related to application
                deNewVirtDir.Properties["AppFriendlyName"].Value = strApplicationNameLocal; // application friendly name
                deNewVirtDir.Properties["AppRoot"].Value = "/LM/W3SVC/" + strWebSiteIDLocal + "/Root/" + strApplicationNameLocal;
                deNewVirtDir.Properties["AppPoolId"].Value = strAppPoolNameLocal; // application pool to use

                // save all the changes so far in case "AppCreate" fails
                deNewVirtDir.CommitChanges();
                deRootVirtDir.CommitChanges();

Comment: // create the application
                deNewVirtDir.Invoke("AppCreate", 1);

                // commit changes
                deNewVirtDir.CommitChanges();
                deRootVirtDir.CommitChanges();
                deNewVirtDir.Close();
                deRootVirtDir.Close();

Comment: sorry about the formatting, I'm new to this web site, not sure how to add new line chars

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add your code as a code block?

Comment: also - the problem does not occur on every machine, I've tested the code on several machines and only about 1/3 of them exhibit the behavior I've described above.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. It's described in Microsoft's KB article 286196: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286196
All my affected machines were Windows Server 2K3 R2 just like described in the article.